# A proof problem with group and order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $g\in G$ be an element of order $n$.

prove that for any $k\in Z$, $g^k=1$ iff $n\mid k$.

My result.

Let $\langle{g}\rangle=\{g^k: k\in\mathbb N\}$.

$k=an+r$, where $0\leq r < n$. 
Hence, $1=g^k=g^{a\cdot n}g^r=g^r$

Since $g^r=1$ and $r<n$, we must have $r=0$ that is $n\mid k$.

(I am still confused with the problem and cannot see how the proof holds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the $k$ such be in $\mathbb{N}$ a natural number. Im not sure what $K$ is.

So the result is: If $n$ is the order of $g$, then for any positive natural number $k$ such that $g^k=1$ we have $n\mid k$.

Proof: We know that $n$ is the smallest positive integer so that $g^n=1$, so if $g^k=1$, then $n\leq k$. Hence, we can write $k=qn+r$, where $r$ is the remainder we get when we divide $k$ by $n$. Thus, $0\leq r<n$. Hence,

$$ 1=g^k=g^{qn+r}=g^{qn}g^r=(g^n)^qg^r=1^qg^r=g^r$$

Since $n$ is the minimal positive number such that $g^n=1$, we must have that $r=0$ because otherwise if $r\neq 0$, then we found a positive number smaller than $n$ (remember that $r$ is the remainder when we divided by $n$, so it must be less than $n$) such that $g^r=1$, this contradicts the definition of $n$. Meaning $k=nq$, so $n$ divides $k$.

Comment: Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks. Corrected the typo.