# If $g$ has order $n$, and $g^m=e$, then $n\mid m$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$ an element of order $n$, *i.e.* $g^n=e$ but $g^p\neq e$ for any $0<p<n$. Show if $g^m=e$, then $n\mid m$.

I want to use $m=qn+r$ with $0\leq r< n$.

Comment: Yes, and what do you know about $g^r$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496904/a-proof-problem-with-group-and-order/496913#496913

Answer (score 4):

If $g^m = e$, then

$$g^m = g^{qn + r} = \left(g^n\right)^q g^r = e^q g^r = g^r$$

On the other hand, $$g^r = e \iff r = 0$$